# Blank after loading from text file

Tags: java

I am trying to output information about TV shows from a text file which looks like this:

```
2
PPL
Tuesday
1900
BBT
Thursday
2100
```

My method to read and output the file looks like this:

```
//method to read shows from file
public static void loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    int i;
    int x = 0;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TV.txt"));
    x = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
    System.out.println(x + " shows!");

    for(i = 0; i < show.size(); i++){
        ((showInfo)show.get(i)).name = input.readLine();
        ((showInfo)show.get(i)).day = input.readLine();
        ((showInfo)show.get(i)).time = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
    }

    System.out.println("Show Information");
    for(i = 0; i < show.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("Name: " + ((showInfo)show.get(i)).name);
        System.out.println("Day: " + ((showInfo)show.get(i)).day);
        System.out.println("Time: " + ((showInfo)show.get(i)).time);
    }    
}
```

It shows me the number of shows and "Show Information" but then it's blank and returns to the main menu. Why is it doing this? Oh and please don't ask why I'm using casting and not generics. I can't because I have to use 1.4. My teacher wants it that way.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: can you format that data as code, so we can see the real structure?

Comment: thanks. Not part of an answer but more general tips: cache that `(showInfo)show.get(i)`. Also, add generics to `show` so you don't have to cast. Assuming it's an ArrayList, `show = new ArrayList<ShowInfo>()` works wonders. Also, you're casting to a class that starts with a lowercase letter. Change that to an uppercase. Sticking to convention keeps your code readable to others =) Finally... what's that `x` for?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans OP has already stated that he can't use generics because of teacher restrictions.

Comment: fair enough. Although this teacher really needs to be made aware that java 1.4 started EOL in 2006 and ended EOL in 2008... forcing students to work with it is insane. >_>

Comment: I agree. Just saying that Sal has an excuse for not using generics for this particular thing. If this were a side-project, or taught by a professor using a more recent version of Java, then that's another story.

Comment: That's what I'm sayin'.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `show` is some `Collection` type.

My best guess is that before you call this function, `show` doesn't actually have anything yet (i.e. `show.size()` is 0).

Since `x` is the number of shows, you should probably be looping like `for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)`, and creating new instances of `showInfo` using your data, and inserting those into `show` within your loop.

Comment: I changed the show.size() to x, but it's giving me an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Now I don't quite understood what you meant by the other stuff.

Comment: Instead of doing `((showInfo)show.get(i))`, create a new `showInfo` object, populate its fields using the data from your file, and then use `show.add()` or equivalent. Remember, `show` is **empty**.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me 77 errors! Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but my code is almost 300 lines long and this is supposed to be a short assignment. I don't want to have to go through all that trouble just to get more errors. Do you know any other way?

Comment: What sort of errors? If `show` is empty to begin with, there's no real way around it; you have to populate it *somehow*.

Comment: No. How would it? The only way you can populate `show` with anything (i.e. the only way `get(i)` is ever going to return something instead of throwing an exception) is *if you put something there yourself*. If you don't explicitly add anything into it, it'll remain empty. All this reading from the file only serves to determine what you insert into `show`. If there's no insert, there's no populating `show`.